# putImageData crashes browser

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi, putimagedata

The putImageData at the end of this code crashes the "Web" browser in Raspberry Pi.

```
    var plotCanvas = document.getElementById("plotCanvas");
    var plotCanvasWidth = plotCanvas.offsetWidth;
    var plotCanvasHeight = plotCanvas.offsetHeight;
    plotCanvasCtx = plotCanvas.getContext("2d");
    var prevImageData = plotCanvasCtx.getImageData(1, 0, plotCanvasWidth -1, plotCanvasHeight);
    plotCanvasCtx.putImageData(prevImageData, 0, 0);
```

It works fine in Windows: FireFox, Chrome, Opera, Internet Explorer.

It doesn't work in Raspberry Pi:

- Web (Epiphany): putImageData crashes the app
- Midori: hangs up at start-up
- Dillo: no JavaScript
- Chromium: can't install

Additional info:

- canvas is 750 x 350 (touchscreen is 800 x 480)
- Raspi version: Raspian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)

The console says:

epiphany-browser: ../../../../src/cairo-surface.c:1626: cairo_surface_mark_dirty_rectangle: Assertion `! _cairo_surface_has_snapshots (surface)' failed.
Aborted

Comment: How big is your canvas? Which raspi version? How did you manage the RAM between graphic and processing?

Comment: I edited my question to add answers to your questions, except I do not understand " How did you manage the RAM between graphic and processing?"